# How does Javascript avoid infinite callback invocation?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

html

```
<p id="test">hello</p>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("called");
  document.getElementById("test").click();
});

document.getElementById("test").click();
```

When I run it, the console only print "called" once. My question is what mechanism does javascript use to avoid calling the callback infinitely?

Comment: If you use a `setTimeout` in the event Listener to perform the next `click`, it does call infinitely. I guess you cannot perform a new `click` before the previous `click` has finished handling. In reality, the browser should be blocked when the event handler is running so no click during event handler is even possible.

Comment: this is not a JS thing this is Browser implementation thing

Comment: I was running this code in Chrome.

Comment: My guess is that the `.click()` function occurs within the same Event Loop as the event callback, and there for the callback signals "complete" and stops. Where as setting a timeout or using `dispatchEvent()` places a brand new call onto the stack, since it runs during subsequent Event Loop iterations it works as expected. Would suspect @Bergi has the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I imagine it might be a debounce thing where it doesn't dispatch another click event while the first one is still running or for a specific time period to stop double click firing event handlers twice.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("called");
  document.getElementById("test").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  }));
});

document.getElementById("test").click();
```

```html
<p id="test">hello</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. Please explain why this works and `.click()` doesn't.

Comment: I am not sure, it was just an experiment.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What answer are you looking for? Implementation details of the browsers code base?

Comment: Just tell me why it behaves like that. I'm not trying to find a way to do infinite callback invocation.

Comment: I gave you my guess on the reason in my answer, to debounce double clicks.

Comment: The fact you can dispatch new events but not call click would collaborate this thought.