# Why doesn't triggering click() inside a click event listener cause an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Can someone explain the program flow of this JavaScript code:

```js
const $leaveRoom = document.querySelector('#leave-button');
let a = 1;
$leaveRoom.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(a);
  console.log("check");
  a++;
  $leaveRoom.click();
  console.log(a);
  a++;
});
```

```html
<button id="leave-button">Leave Room</button>
```

```
The Output was:
1
check
2
check
3
4
```

This question may sound dumb but I am new to JavaScript. I am not able to understand the program flow of this code. I want to know how did I get 3 & 4 in the output.

Comment: you are dealing with a recursive type function. (a function that calls itself)  It's not exactly that but sort of.  On click 1 and check are output. then the program calls the click function and 2 and check are outputed. then the second part of the first click outputs 3 and finally the second part of the inside call to the click functions outputs 4

Comment: @DCR *"then the second part of the first click outputs"* - but why it doesn't trigger a new click there? Why it exits?

Comment: @DCR - What exactly makes this code not a traditional recursion?

Comment: I'm not sure what OP is asking. The most interesting part of this code seems to boil down to "why does calling `el.click()` inside an element's own event handler not cause an infinite chain of events to fire?" The downvotes are probably because it's not clear what is surprising to OP here, so I'm assuming it's the click call rather than the increment or delayed final `console.log`s, which could be illustrated without events just as well.

Comment: typical recursion has an end case and a way of reducing the problem on each iteration until you reach the end case

Comment: @Mister Jojo Yeah I know that but I am having confusion in understanding that which one between 3 & 4 came due to click()

Comment: @TusharAgarwal wrapping the click function call in a `setTimeout` seems to trigger infinitely. I have no clue why though, maybe someone can shed some light on that.

Comment: @Mister Jojo okay...but can you explain me why its happening...like the working of it.

Comment: @Mister Jojo That's true but so what.  Do you know why this doesn't produce an endless loop?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452886/how-does-javascript-avoid-infinite-callback-invocation) is a very similar question but interestingly no definitive answers either. Will we ever know?

Comment: @Danoram the explanation is in my answer below, it's about the hidden flag named `click in progres`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> The key to this question is the presence of a **hidden Flag** on each `element.click()` method.
>
> > **Each element has an associated click in progress flag, which is initially unset.**

the doc: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#dom-click

As soon as this method is activated, this flag changes from `progess Status == unset` to `progess Status == active` *(pseudo code)*

(then it returns to its initial status once the code it contains is fully executed)

When this flag is in the `active` state, then any call to this method is ignored.

---

Here is my original post to show the execution sequence of `console.log()`

```js
const bt_leaveRoom = document.querySelector('#leave-button')
var counter = 0
var origin  = 'event clic'

bt_leaveRoom.addEventListener('click', () => 
  {
  let source = origin
  console.log(`_first console.log(): counter = ${ ++counter }, origin = ${source}`)

  origin = 'call'
  bt_leaveRoom.click()
  
  console.log(`second console.log(): counter = ${ ++counter }, origin = ${source}`)
  })
```

```html
<button id="leave-button">Leave Room</button>
```

the Hidden Flag act like in the same way if I have coded this way :
replace this line:
`bt_leaveRoom.click()`
to:
`if (source !== 'call') bt_leaveRoom.click()`

But in fact the system use the method hidden flag (named `progress flag` ?)
which can be *(in pseudo code)*

```
if (progress_flag_of_bt_leaveRoom.click() is unset) do { bt_leaveRoom.click() }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Why doesn't calling $leaveRoom.click() inside the function create an endless loop?  Basically, it would seem like the second console.log() statement should never get executed

Comment: You got it, the click in progres flag is the key. What about making this more prominent in your answer? Like at the begining, with a clear quote of the specs "If this element's click in progress flag is set, then return." and with a reminder that calling HTMLElement.click() calls the event handlers synchronously? And then why not even remove the rest because it really doesn't add much?

Comment: @Kaiido   I left the second `console.log()` to respect the PO question, and show the logical continuation of the execution. But it's true it's not very useful

Comment: Yes, if my may, you should really 1. Move the "click in progress" part at the beginning, it's the key of the problem here, don't hide it under unrelated stuff. 2. Change the quote. We don't care there is a flag set to false initially, what matters is that when `click()` is called, this flag is used to early exit, so quote the part that says that. 3. Explain that Event triggered by `click()` like `dispatchEvent` are fired synchronously, and thus the flag stays raised in between and this also explains the order of logs, if you want to keep it as a footer.

Comment: @Mister Jojo Thanks for that...so let me summarise it once.
1.) 'click in progress flag' is initially unset.
2.) If 'click in progress flag' is "unset" then only Element.click() will run.
3.) Once Element.click() function runs then 'click in progress flag' will become "set".
4.) If 'click in progress flag' is set then element.click() will end due to return.
Right?

Comment: @TusharAgarwal Yes, that's about it, this hidden flag prevents the element.click() method from being used recursively

Comment: @Mister Jojo Yeah bro I did that.

Comment: @Mister Jojo Can you explain why same code runs for infinite times when .click() is used inside setTimeout() function. You can refer to the 2nd most voted answer if you're not able to understand my question.

Comment: @TusharAgarwal the `setTimeout` works in a separate process, and even if the chosen delay is zero, this call is made late enough for all the instructions to be carried out to be completed, and this `Flag` is therefore returned to its `unset state` before. In his example the `setTimeout` is the last instruction, which is enough to make the `Flag` go back to `unset`. On the other hand, if there were other instructions following, then the `Flag` would not be returned to `unset` and the call would have been rejected. unless you put a sufficiently long delay in the `setTimeout`

Comment: I'd say that this _then it returns to its initial status once the code it contains is fully executed_ is a bit inaccurate. It should be _then it returns to its initial status once the **synchronous** code it contains is fully executed_ Not sure, if anyone mentioned it before.

Answer (score 14):

I tried a couple of things to find an answer to this question. I haven't really found a definitive answer to what's going on here, but I do believe that what I share here feeds into this excellent problem.

I simplified the code to focus on the recursive triggering of events.

**Simplified Code**

```js
const $leaveRoom = document.querySelector('#leave-button');
let a = 1;
$leaveRoom.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(a++);
    $leaveRoom.click();
});
```

```html
<button id="leave-button">Leave Room</button>
```

We can see here that we have two calls for `console.log`, the first one is for the actual clicking of the button, and the second one is for the call to `$leaveRoom.click();`. It seems to stop there for some reason.

**Using `dispatchEvent`**

```js
const $leaveRoom = document.querySelector('#leave-button');
let a = 1;
$leaveRoom.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(a++);
    $leaveRoom.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
});
```

```html
<button id="leave-button">Leave Room</button>
```

Here, the event is triggered multiple times (44 for me), this could be due to how fast your machine is. It seems to stop triggering eventually though, so I'm thinking the same phenomenon is happening here as well.

**Using `setTimeout`**

```js
const $leaveRoom = document.querySelector('#leave-button');
let a = 1;
$leaveRoom.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(a++);
    setTimeout(() => { $leaveRoom.click(); });
});
```

```html
<button id="leave-button">Leave Room</button>
```

If you are looking for a way to infinitely trigger the click event, regardless of why the previous methods fail. This does seem to do the trick.

Having said all this, I still have no clue about this hidden force that stops the recursion for the previous methods. Maybe someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: That 44 times is really suspicious. I wonder what causes this limit.

Comment: Yes, would be engine-dependent though. I guess it's some internal queue or stack size limit.

Comment: As you said @Bergi, it is definitely engine dependent. In Chrome and Edge, I get the 44 count and then an error is logged to the console "Maximum call stack size exceeded."  In FireFox, it goes 383 times and then logs an error "undefined" in the console.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const click1 = document.querySelector('#click1')
const click2 = document.querySelector('#click2')
const click3 = document.querySelector('#click3')

click1.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log("click1")
  click2.click()
});
click2.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log("click2")
  click3.click()
});
click3.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  console.log("click3")
  click1.click()
});
```

```html
<button id="click1">Click 1</button>
<button id="click2">Click 2</button>
<button id="click3">Click 3</button>
```

Actually it appears there is loop breaking logic in the event handling. The handlers will happily daisy chain user input events until the initial interaction dispatches a duplicate event. Then it will no longer dispatch any.

Comment: "However, chrome imposes a limit on user input events from scripts." Sources? Also the behavior seems consistent across browsers.